# Use value of a property to check another property instead of using Generic

Tags: typescript

I am designing a type definition like this

```
type ApiConfig<TagTypes extends string[]> = {
  selectedTags: Array<TagTypes[number]>
}
```

My purpose is to force the value selectedTags has to be an array that is a subset of TagTypes like this:

```
const apiConfig: ApiConfig<["Post", "Comment"]> = {
  selectedTags: ["Comment"], // TypeScript will not complain.
}
const apiConfig: ApiConfig<["Post", "Comment"]> = {
  selectedTags: ["Comment", "User"], // TypeScript will complain.
}
```

Now I want the TagTypes also available at run time as well so I updated my code

```
type ApiConfig<TagTypes extends string[]> = {
  tagTypes: TagTypes
  selectedTags: Array<TagTypes[number]>
}

const apiConfig: ApiConfig<["Post", "Comment"]> = {
  tagTypes: ["Post", "Comment"],
  selectedTags: ["Comment"],
}
```

It is easy to see that the ["Post", "Comment"] part is duplicated. How can I prevent that?
I want to the selectedTags is a subset of tagTypes. Does TypeScript provide a way to define this?

Comment: The easiest way would be to have a dummy generic factory function that will do the job. Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWBhA9gOwGbwOYB4AqAhlnuBAM5QQAewEqAJhQE4QH1oA2IUZwT8qLAG0AugD4oAXigBvAFBRFUYERKQyALiiFipMgqVkIHCAGNa9HZthMmBEPlV6hqAK4BbAEYQm4uQF85OVM0XihTFgJaOCQ0TCwpKBwQ1DCdNXJKGjpGKEj2VC4ePgFhcQAKFV11LRiUDGxHavIxAEopCSqM-WDQ4CgCBHr4xIjWaKG47HL5JWUnGqghACIABWReZYAaKGWUd3c6YGWRLYNFIxNzCEsiaxX9w9Rj04DWuSA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame perfect, that's what I am looking for. I don't mind adding a factory function. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the type based on a value instead.

```
type ApiConfig<TagTypes extends string[]> = {
  tagTypes: TagTypes
  selectedTags: Array<TagTypes[number]>
}

const API_TAGS = ["Post", "Comment"] as const;
type ApiTags = typeof API_TAGS;
const apiConfig: ApiConfig<ApiTags> = {
  tagTypes: API_TAGS,
  selectedTags: ["Comment"],
}
```

The only problem with that is you used string[] for the TagTypes parameter, which makes constant types fail because they will not allow you to use array operations with any string. We can fix it by rewriting the original type like so:

```
type ApiConfig<Tag extends string> = {
  selectedTags: Tag[];
}

const API_TAGS = ["Post", "Comment"] as const;
type ApiTag = (typeof API_TAGS)[number];
const apiConfig: ApiConfig<ApiTag> = {
  tagTypes: API_TAGS,
  selectedTags: ["Comment"],
}
```